# PDO retrieve all fields with value 1 and echo with alternate name

Tags: pdo

i have a table (facility) in which field names are swimming_pool, restaurant, WiFi, library etc.
if a particular house having only two of those facilities available, i give those available field names value 1 and if not 0.
I want to retrieve all the field names with value 1 and echo each field with value 1 with an alternate name.

here is what i want to achieve

```
    $st = $db->prepare(select * from facility where house_id = ?);
    $st->execute(array($_GET['house_id']));
    $row = $st->fetch();
```

from above i have to select all fields with value 1. And for all those fields with value one i have to echo name (for example: if swimming_pool value is 1 i have to echo Swimming Pool, if it is 0 then check for the next column)

i hope you understood my goal.

Comment: Pdo has nothing to do with this question. Just echo hatever fields you want from $row

Answer (score -1):

I hope I solved your question? I didn't test it yet, so if there might be a problem, do a comment.

```
<?php
/*
* Sample Link: web.com/index.php?house_id=1&search=1,0,0,1
*/

/*
* Sample Fields:
* swimming_pool, restaurant, wifi, library
*/

//Explode the $_GET['search'] to create an array
$fields_to_search = explode(",",$_GET['search']);

//Manually set the fields
$db_fields = [
        'swimming_pool',
        'restaurant',
        'wifi',
        'library'
];

$fields_to_be_selected = "";

//Create a counter as basis to store if the Link is 1 or 0, then pass it to $db_fields[]
$counter = 0;
foreach($fields_to_search as $field) {
    //Check if $field is 1
    if($field == 1) {
        //Then pass it to $table_to_be_selected and add a COMMA
        $fields_to_be_selected .= $db_fields[$counter].",";
    }
    $counter++;
}
//Remove the last COMMA
$fields_to_be_selected = substr($fields_to_be_selected,0,-1);

/*
* LASTLY DO THE prepare()
*/
$query = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM `facility` WHERE `house_id` = ?",$fields_to_be_selected);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['house_id']));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


//It will only print the selected fields
print_r($rows);

?>
```

Comment: i totally didn't understand this because am new to PDO. However i tried a lot to with above code and did not get any results. My table name is facility. And table fields are house_id, swimming_pool, restaurant, WiFi, library etc. As i said before all fields value will be 1 or 0. if house has particular facility value will be 1. if not it will be 0. I want to retrieve all fields with value 1 and print or echo those fields. However i do not want to echo value 1. Instead of value 1 i need to echo Swimming pool, WiFi, Restaurant, Library etc. Is this possible using a loop?